# Spectrum of a Laurent polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

I suspect this question is either easy/known or far too general to answer, but I'm finding it difficult to google for so I'd appreciate directions to good resources on the subject.

Can we describe all the prime ideals of the commutative Laurent polynomial ring in n variables over a field (let's say char 0, alg closed) or is this a completely hopeless task for n > 1?

I'm aware that you can use, say, Groebner bases to test for primality given a specific ideal, but can the whole spectrum be described/classified in any way?

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think it should be an [algebraic torus](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Algebraic_torus), since the group functor $\mathbf{G}_m\colon Alg_k \to Grp$ is represented by $k[X,X^{-1}]$. This is definitely the case over $\Bbb C$, which you can find, e.g., in the book [Toric varieties](http://www.amazon.com/Toric-Varieties-Graduate-Studies-Mathematics/dp/0821848194) by Cox, Little, and Schenck (example 1.0.2, page 5).

Comment: The question is too general.

Comment: I had a feeling it would be.  That partly answers my question, in a way - I'm not a commutative algebraist, so I first wanted to check there wasn't some well-known classification and I simply wasn't googling the right terms.

Okay, so n=1 is easy; what about n=2, ie $k[x^{\pm1},y^{\pm1}]$?  Is that already too difficult to describe the prime spectrum explicitly?

Comment: A.P., it looks like that book uses Spec to mean Maxspec, i.e. the torus only gives me the maximal ideals.

Comment: @Eithil: On an algebraically closed field $k$, by the [Nullstellensatz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullstellensatz#Formulation), every point in $V(I)$ for $I\subset k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$ is rational, i.e. it corresponds to a maximal ideal in $k[X_1,\dotsc,X_n]$.

Comment: Yep, but I'm after the prime spectrum, not the maximal spectrum.  Algebraic geometry isn't my strong point, am I missing something?  Are you saying I can consider $V(P)$ for $P$ prime in $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ and somehow use the fact that every point in $V(P)$ corresponds to a maximal ideal to understand $P$?

Comment: Scrap my last comment. I though you wanted to describe the spectrum geometrically. I fear that Martin Brandenburg is right in saying that the question of describing all the prime ideals is too general.

Comment: @A.P. How is the case $n=1$ easy? I know that $K[x^{\pm1}]$ is a PID, but what are its prime elements? In $\mathbb{Z}$ or $K[x]$ there is no classification of prime elements.

Comment: @Leon I never said that the case $n = 1$ is easy. I started with "I'm not sure about this, but", which you could paraphrase as "based on my current knowledge, I would guess that". The knowledge in question is the *specific* case of $\mathbb{C}[X,X^{-1}]$, for which I gave a reference.